# Navigation Drawer push animation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I made an app that uses the Navigation Drawer and in which I added several fragments (called: Audi / BMW / Kia /...etc ).Now I want to animate the transition between the Drawer's Panel and the Fragment.
I saw on an app a cool transition where the new activity pushes the drawer back to the left.Any idea on how the .xml file would look with that kind of animation?

A piece from the MainActivity.java

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Audi();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new BMW();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Volkswagen();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Kia();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Volvo();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.fade_in);
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

fade_in.xml

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

I'm still looking for a "push" animation that works in my case...

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far with the xml adding the fragments?

Comment: Updated, take a look